# Manejo de sesiones con react

Tags: reactjs

soy nuevo en React y he seguido un tutorial para la construcción de un sitio. He utilizado `react-router-dom`  para separar los componentes en rutas.

La estructura de mi `App.js` se encuentra de la siguiente

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar'
import Dashboard from './components/dashboard/Dashboard'
import ProjectDetails from './components/projects/ProjectDetails'
import SignIn from './components/auth/SignIn';
import SignUp from './components/auth/SignUp';
import CreateProject from './components/projects/CreateProject'



class App extends Component {
  
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
          <Route path="/project/:id" component={ProjectDetails} />
          <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
          <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
          <Route path="/create" component={CreateProject} />
        </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Deseo que cuando la aplicación entre a / que es Dashboard, si no esta logeado (una variable de tipo true o false) sea redireccionado a la ruta '/signin'.

Dashboard:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Notifications from './Notifications'
import ProjectList from '../projects/ProjectList'

class Dashboard  extends Component {
    
    render() {

        return(
            <div className="dashboard container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col s12 m6">
                        <ProjectList />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col s12 m5 offset-m1">
                        <Notifications />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Dashboard
```

Login:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class SignIn extends Component {
    state ={
        email : '',
        password: ''
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.id]: e.target.value
        })
    }
    handleSubmmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmmit} className="white">
                    <h5 className="grey-text text-darken-3">Sign In</h5>
                    <div className="input-field">
                        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field">
                        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field">
                        <button className="btn pink lighten-1 z-depth-0">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SignIn
```

¿Me podrían guiar para realizarlo? el proceso de si el usuario esta loggeado, será una funcion que devolvera true o false dependiendo si el usuario esta en una lista de un servicio REST que se consultará. Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Si es REST, por definición, no hay estado o sesiones. Tienes que buscar otra manera. Y dado que no hay un problema específico y se presta a opiniones, es candidata para cierre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { Component, useEffect } from 'react'
import Notifications from './Notifications'
import ProjectList from '../projects/ProjectList'
Import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'

// user debes pasarlo o como prop o como custom hook o context.

class Dashboard  extends Component {
Const history= useHistory()
useEffect(()=>{
        If (!user) { history.push('/') }
}, [user])
render() {

    return(
        <div className="dashboard container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col s12 m6">
                    <ProjectList />
                </div>
                <div className="col s12 m5 offset-m1">
                    <Notifications />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}
export default Dashboard
```

// post data, no sigas tutoriales con clase. Componentes funcionales y hooks es lo nuevo. Busca los tutoriales de midu.dev

Answer (score 0):

creo que tengo la solución para tu problema, que en realidad no es tan grande, ya a mi me pasó algo parecido y encontré una forma que según internet es muy buena jajaja. Consiste en utilizar “history” de ‘react-router-dom’ y “withRouter”.  Debajo te adjunto tu Dashboard con los cambios que te sugiero. Te aconsejo que dediques unos minutos a buscar en internet información relacionada con todo esto para que entiendas más al detalle cómo funciona esta técnica. No obstante, si tienes cualquier duda puntual no dudes en comentar.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Notifications from './Notifications'
import ProjectList from '../projects/ProjectList'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';//Agregado

class Dashboard extends Component {

//Funcion agregada
verificaUsuario = () => {
 if (tu usiario existe) {
  return this.props.history.push('/');
 }
};

render() {
 this.verificaUsuario();//Agregado
 return (
  <div className="dashboard container">
   <div className="row">
    <div className="col s12 m6">
     <ProjectList />
    </div>
    <div className="col s12 m5 offset-m1">
     <Notifications />
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 )
}
}

export default withRouter(Dashboard);//Agregado
```